# Configure Bootstrap 3/4 css with Ionic 2 application

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, ionic2

I would like to get the features of all the bootstrap 3 or 4 css in my Ionic 2 framework application.

I followed the steps to install bootstrap css as it showed for bootstrap css integration with angular 2.

For Ionic 2 it is not working, what are the configuration steps for the Ionic 2 framework?

Answer (score 0):

i add external library to my project using this technique.

1. create on root project one folder "scripts"
2. create inside this folder one js file "custom.lib.js"
3. export a modules inside this file.
4. first 5 elements are ionic config (copy and paste)
5. then add wherever lib you want include on ionic (i left you one example for font-awesome lib).
6. override "ionic_copy" config on package.json, create one session inside package.json call.

   "config": {
       "ionic_copy": "./scripts/custom.lib.js"
     },

i hope that help you.

```
 module.exports = {
      copyAssets: {
        src: ['{{SRC}}/assets/**/*'],
        dest: '{{WWW}}/assets'
      },
      copyIndexContent: {
        src: ['{{SRC}}/index.html', '{{SRC}}/manifest.json', '{{SRC}}/service-worker.js'],
        dest: '{{WWW}}'
      },
      copyFonts: {
        src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/**/*', '{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*'],
        dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/fonts'
      },
      copyPolyfills: {
        src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionic-angular/polyfills/polyfills.js'],
        dest: '{{BUILD}}'
      },
      copySwToolbox: {
        src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/sw-toolbox/sw-toolbox.js'],
        dest: '{{BUILD}}'
      },
      copyFontAwesomeCSS: {
        src: '{{ROOT}}/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/css/'
      },
      copyFontAwesome: {
        src: '{{ROOT}}/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**/*',
        dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/fonts/'
      }
    };
```

[image: package.json]
[image: custom.lib.js]